# Cannot upload file to FTP from Excel's VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, ftp, macros

I need to automate uploading file to FTP server from within Excel's macro.

I'm following a simple path of creating script file and then running FTP.exe with commands from that script file. The problem is, that if FTP.exe is executed from within VBA script, file is not uploaded correctly - it gets created, but has 0 bytes on the server. But when I run FTP command from the shell (with exact same script file), file gets uploaded correctly.

My script looks like following:

```
Sub Przycisk1_Klikniecie()

TempScriptFile = "D:\Temporary\ScriptFile.txt"
SourcePath = "(local path)"
SourceFilename = "(local file)"

Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

Open TempScriptFile For Output As #1
Print #1, "open (host)"
Print #1, "(user)"
Print #1, "(password)"
Print #1, "binary"
Print #1, "lcd " & SourcePath
Print #1, "put " & SourceFilename
Print #1, "bye"
Print #1, "exit"
Close #1

If FSO.FolderExists("C:\Windows\System32") = False Then
    Shell "C:\WINNT\system32\cmd /c ftp.exe -s:" & TempScriptFile, vbNormalFocus
Else
    Shell "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd /c ftp.exe -s:" & TempScriptFile, vbNormalFocus
End If

Kill TempScriptFile

End Sub
```

Environment: Windows 10, Microsoft Office 2013.

As a note: the same script works on two different machines (Win7/Office 2007 and Win10/Office 2016).

What am I doing wrong?

---

Here is the log from FTP executed from Excel:

```
ftp> open <host>
Connected to <host>.
220 FTP Server
---> OPTS UTF8 ON
500 OPTS UTF8 not understood

User (<host>:(none)): 
---> USER <user>
331 Password required for <user>

---> PASS <password>
230 User <user> logged in
ftp> lcd <folder>
Local directory now <folder>
ftp> binary
---> TYPE I
200 Type set to I
ftp> put <file>
---> PORT 10,132,8,219,197,121
200 PORT command successful
---> STOR <file>
425 Unable to build data connection: Connection timed out
ftp> bye
---> QUIT
221 Goodbye.
```

Note the `425 Unable to build data connection: Connection timed out`. Why does it happen?

Comment: Have you ruled out permission issues? Is Excel running in the same security context as you trying it on the command line? Another thought.. redirect the output from the command when it runs, maybe that will point you in the right direction... e.g.: Shell "C:\Windows\system32\cmd /c ftp.exe -s:" & TempScriptFile & " >> D:\Temporary\Output.txt", vbNormalFocus

Comment: @BrianC Thanks for the comment. I added logging and now I see, that when trying to upload file, connection times out. What may cause this?

Comment: My guess is that you have client side antivirus / firewall that's preventing the data connection from working when the code is launched from excel. Try disabling them temporarily and see if anything changes

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with this issue for months. Finally stumbled across the solution today. There are two ftp.exe applications on a 64-bit Windows (System32 and SysWOW64). Only the System32 version was being allowed through my Windows Defender firewall. I added the other one, and it now works perfectly!